# Is there a way to boost Rise and Arise Hit Rates?

Tags: final-fantasy-tactics

One of the problems I have with Final Fantasy Tactics: War of the lions is how Rise and Arise work, most of the time their hit rate is just over 50% and even when I had it over 75% it still kept missing.

Because of this, a lot of my character, even though has practically mastered their job, remain in that job cause I still need their Item Action Ability

For example: I try and keep Agrias's Holy Sword Ability even though I'm trying to get her to level up the jobs to get the Ninja Job so she can learn Dual Wield and then revert back to her Holy Knight Job.

Another example: my white mage has to remain a white mage for her cure magic despite the fact I want her to learn some summons.

So, I'm wondering if there is a why to boost the hit rate of rise and arise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand what Raise and Arise success rates have to do with changing your character's jobs.

Nonethless, the success rate should be calculated by:
(Magic Attack + PWR)*(Faith/100)*(Target's Faith/100)

Comment: you can loose characters permanently if they turn into a crystal and if Ramza turns into a Crystal it's Game Over. Unless your going to go into every battle and not get anyone killed or clear the map before anyone turns into a crystal then then you need resurrecting items in which case, your white mage is stuck as a white mage due to the fact that her resurrection magic which would keep her from the front lines keeps missing and the moment she rushes out to use an item she'll be killed which means another character needs items to bring her back

Comment: Item's is a separate Action Ability so which has to be equipped when the character is not a chemist so a lot of characters are forced to stay in one job even after it's mastered just so that they can use that's job's kills and have items ready to bring back your white mage who is forced onto the front lines or any other character who is about to turn into a crystal

Comment: @Memor-X I strongly feel your missing some major points on how to properly play this game from your descriptions. Nobody is forced into anything even WITH the crystal system. It's entirly too easy to have 2 toons equipped with Item as a secondary action stat to prevent perma deaths.

Comment: Zodiac Symbol compatibility is also going to be a factor. Compatibility chart found here: https://finalfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/Zodiac_(term)